# Custom segue with separate moving background

Tags: uiviewcontroller, segue, transition, modalviewcontroller

I want to achieve an effect like in this animation

[image: Segue Animation]

There should be two (or more) `ViewControllers` in my App that have a custom segue. The transition should just move the new `ViewController` up. And in the background there should be an image, which moves a bit with every segue.

I thought about 3 `ViewControllers` in total. One for the background, handling the background movement and displaying `ViewController1` and `2` modally. But I don't know how to achieve that. Has anyone a better approach or another idea?

**EDIT**
if the animation doesn't start, open the .gif in another tab to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: This is just an idea of something you could do. Your situation sounds very specific and custom segue's can get very complex very fast. So this code might not do exactly what you need it to. This offers an insight into how I've solved similar problems in the past.

---

I'm not entirely sure of your question, but I can tell you what I've done in the past.

First, I create a custom segue class that inherits from UIStoryboardSegue. I'm going to assume you know how to set up your storyboard to use the segue (i.e. wire up a button event or similar). The class I give for that is my custom segue class.

In this class's `perform` method, I'm utilizing UIStoryboardSegue's `sourceViewController` and `destinationViewController` properties to access the view's. I add the destination view controller's view to the source view controller's view hierarchy. That way I can animate it out.

For your case, you could create a `@protocol` that gives access to your background property like this:

**ViewControllerWithBackground.h**

```
@protocol ViewControllerWithBackground

@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *backgroundImage;

@end
```

Assign that protocol to each of your view controller's that will be using the segue. In the segue code, you could then move the background up/down in the class's `perform` method to perform the segue as follows:

**Custom UIStoryboardSegue method**

```
- (void)perform {
    UIViewController *sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destinationViewController = self.destinationViewController;

    if ([self.sourceViewController conformsToProtocol:@protocol(ViewControllerWithBackground)] &&
            [self.destinationViewController conformsToProtocol:@protocol(ViewControllerWithBackground)]) {

        UIViewController<ViewControllerWithBackground> *sourceViewController = (UIViewController<ViewControllerWithBackground> *)self.sourceViewController;
        UIViewController<ViewControllerWithBackground> *destinationViewController = (UIViewController<ViewControllerWithBackground> *)self.destinationViewController;

        // Remove the existing view from the frame so we can animate it separately
        UIView *sourceView = sourceViewController.view;

        // Place a container view onto the frame that will contain the destination view and the current view
        sourceViewController.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:sourceView.frame];

        // Add the destination view controller's view and the place the source view on top of it so it's hidden
        [sourceViewController.view addSubview:destinationViewController.view];
        [sourceViewController.view addSubview:sourceView];

        // Set the final destination for the background image (i.e. where do you want it to end up in the destination view)
        CGRect currentBackgroundFrame = sourceViewController.backgroundImage.frame;
        CGRect finalBackgroundPosition = CGRectMake(0, 0, currentBackgroundFrame.size.width, currentBackgroundFrame.size.height); // ADD X,Y VALUES TO ANIMATE IT TO HERE

        // We are setting the background image's frame for the destination view controller here. (Remember: it's hidden the source view controller's view right now)
        destinationViewController.backgroundImage.frame = finalBackgroundPosition;

        // Animate everything
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
            // We are animating the original view's background image only
            sourceViewController.backgroundImage.frame = finalBackgroundPosition;

            // OTHER ANIMATION VALUES HERE

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            // We have to dispatch because there will be unbalanced calls for begin/end transition because this transition hasn't finished executing
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                [sourceViewController presentViewController:destinationViewController animated:NO completion:^{
                    // Reset the view hierarchy to the original for unwinding (optional)
                    sourceViewController.view = sourceView;
                }];
            });

        }];

    }
}
```

**Optional**

If you need code to be able to tell if the background image should move up or down, don't forget you've subclassed the segue so you can pass that information from your view controller's `prepareForSegue:sender:` method to your custom segue's `perform` method like so:

**Source View Controller Example**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    // Code that tells me this event requires the background to animate like it's moving up instead of down

    if ([segue isKindClass:[CustomStoryBoardBackgroundThingSegue class]]) {
        CustomStoryBoardBackgroundThingSegue *customSegue = (CustomStoryBoardBackgroundThingSegue *)segue;
        segue.animateUp = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I think I am going to make it with your tips. But one question. Why do you want to add the `destinationViewController.view` to the `sourceViewController.view`? Can't I just use both separately. You know, I don't understand the point of doing this :D Both nevertheless a big thank you. It helped me a lot!

Comment: I was using this to animate and fade out the source view controller. Because the destination view controller wasn't on the stack at the time until the `presentViewController...` method it would fade out to a white screen. The destination view was placed behind to give it something to fade into until the destination view controller was in the view stack.

Comment: Do you know how to write this line in swift? `UIViewController<ViewControllerWithBackground> *sourceViewController = (UIViewController<ViewControllerWithBackground> *)self.sourceViewController;`